# angular "potentially unsafe regular expression"

Tags: angular5

I'm following the instructions at https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt0
Using VS Code on Win10.

After creating a new Angular project with "ng new " then "ng serve --open" I get the error message:

> potentially unsafe regular expression: ^(?:(?!(?:[[!*+?$^"'.\/]+)).)+

The full error message is at the end of this post.

ng -v gives:

```
Node: 8.9.4
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.5
...
    @angular/cli: 1.7.0
    @angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.1
    @angular-devkit/core: 0.3.1
    @angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.1
    @ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
    @ngtools/webpack: 1.10.0
    @schematics/angular: 0.3.1
    @schematics/package-update: 0.3.1
    typescript: 2.5.3
    webpack: 3.11.0
```

I cannot find any reference to this error anywhere. I'm new to Angular, can anyone assist with this error please?

The full error message is:

```
Error: potentially unsafe regular expression: ^(?:(?!(?:[\[!*+?$^"'.\\/]+)).)+
    at Function.toRegex.create (C:\VS_Code\NewProjects\angular-tour-of-heroes\node_modules\regex-not\index.js:62:11)
    at createTextRegex (C:\VS_Code\NewProjects\angular-tour-of-heroes\node_modules\nanomatch\lib\parsers.js:378:22)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\VS_Code\NewProjects\angular-tour-of-heroes\node_modules\nanomatch\lib\parsers.js:14:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\VS_Code\NewProjects\angular-tour-of-heroes\node_modules\nanomatch\index.js:16:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
```

Answer (score 0):

> - delete `node_modules`
> - reinstall everything

Refs:

- https://github.com/jonschlinkert/regex-not/issues/3#issuecomment-366850811
- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9692